# MYSQL query multiple tables conditional sql

Tags: mysql

I have a table table for posts, and a table for friends list.

```
Posts:
id | PosterUsername | title | info1 | info2 | etc.

Friends:
user | friend | blocked(boolean)
```

So basically I am looking for a sql query that I can filter the results so that the active user can only view posts that are posted by someone who has added them as a friend.

something like..

```
SELECT * FROM Posts WHERE
FROM Friends user = PosterUsername AND friend = 'activeUsername' AND BLOCKED = '0'
```

I can think of a way where I basically store the entire list of people that have added the 'activeUser' as a friend inside a variable and then as I loop through displaying the posts I can just check against it and only display the ones that meet the condition. But I am not very familiar with advances MYSQL commands, I am guessing there is a better way.

Update :

[image]

Comment: Question: Are friend relationships bidirectional?  What I mean by this, does an entry in the `Friends` table mean that both friends are in a relationship, or could it mean a one way relationship?

Comment: Try this:  `SELECTION * FROM Posts INNER JOIN Friends ON (Posts.id = Friends.friend) WHERE user='current user' AND blocked = 0;`

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen it could be a one way relationship. It could also be both.. but the purpose is to only show the posts to the posters friends.

Answer (score 2):

One option here would be to join together the `Friends` and `Posts` table, connecting a user's friends with the posts written by those friends:

```
SELECT p.*
FROM Friends f INNER JOIN Posts p
    ON f.friend = p.PosterUsername
WHERE f.user = 'current user' AND f.blocked = FALSE
```

Comment: I will research this method and let you know if it works, thanks!

Comment: If you add some sample data, it would help in determining the exact query you need.

Answer (score -4):

Without writing actual code since I'm on my phone, you'll want to:

```
Select *
from posts 
where posterid in (
    select friendid 
    from friends 
    where userid =loggedinuserid)
```

Something like that should do the trick.

Comment: if you cant write a coherent answer for what ever reason, then don't

Comment: Dagon what exactly is incoherent about that message?